# Google speech API - only transcribe from a given set of words or ban certain words?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

Is it possible to restrict the Google Speech API to only recognize from a given set of words? Alternatively, is it possible to "ban" certain words? If not, is it possible with any other speech API that supports German?

I do know that I can set hint phrases via a speech context. Still it rather recognizes a different word.

As an example, I use the API mostly for the German language. I want to recognize the word "stärker" (which is also listed as a speech context hint), though, the API mostly transcribes it to "Stärke" unless I pronounce the "r" at the end unnaturally strong. So, is it possible to prevent the speech API from transcribing that word, for instance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you are thinking about this wrong - what if you apply a filter before/after the speech recognition and filter the words there instead?

Comment: Tha'ts what I am currently doing. I am just considering if it is somehow possible with the API itself which would be easier/cleaner.

Comment: Does anybody know if this is possible on the Alexa Speech API?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible with Google Speech API.  I don't know if it's possible with other speech recognition services.

Answer (score 0):

Google speech API supports set of parameters in RecognitionConfig.
There is an optional boolean parameter called "profanityFilter", which filters out profanities.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig